# cURL, frames & letitbit.net: Could you help me please?

Tags: php, curl

I have written a script for Letitbit.net. With help of cURL I can get to the page where after 60 secs is to appear the link to the file I want to download. That page uses frames... If I get to the page via a browser, the sourse code looks just like this:

```
<frameset rows="125,70,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame src="http://letitbit.net/tmpl/tmpl_frame_topad.php" name="mainFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="mainFrame" title="topFrame" />
  <frame src="http://letitbit.net/tmpl/tmpl_frame_top.php?link=http://r3.letitbit.net/download100/7930.7504ba9eaf495fe8945741a1d3_tybujkhg9e17poo/719028/letitbit.net/___2.7z" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="topFrame" />
  <frame src="http://letitbit.net/wawname/letitbit.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
</frameset>
```

But when this is done with my PHP script I get this:

```
<frameset rows="125,70,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame src="http://letitbit.net/tmpl/tmpl_frame_topad.php" name="mainFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="mainFrame" title="topFrame" />
  <frame src="http://letitbit.net/tmpl/tmpl_frame_top.php?link=" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="topFrame" />
  <frame src="http://letitbit.net/wawname/letitbit.html" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
</frameset>
```

That is where the actual link is missing. (http://r3.letitbit.net/download100/7930.7504ba9eaf495fe8945741a1d3_tybujkhg9e17poo/719028/letitbit.net/___2.7z) What's the problem? Could you please give me some clues?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the JavaScript. it might be writing the link dynamically.

Comment: That is all sourse code you could find on the page. No JS at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're sending all cookies and POST arguments to /download3.php

Notable cookies:

```
advm
coutnry
mgid
pop
ref_full
ref_site
reserv
```

Notable POST'ed form arguments:

```
uid
md5crypt
cap
frameset
uid2
uid5
uid
name
pin
realuid
realname
host
ssserver
sssize
optiondir
fix
```

Failure to send correct values for any of those could conceivably cause the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

@Frank Farmer: bro, there was the frameset argument missed in my request, but where did you find the fix cookie?

This is all the form has:

```
<form action="http://letitbit.net/download3.php" method="post" id="dvifree">
   <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="2245376a60aebc53938549a0c4716a9d" />
   <input type="hidden" name="md5crypt" value="aHR0cDovL3I1NC5sZXRpdGJpdC5uZXQvZG93bmxvYWQ1MC8yYjQ0NmUzNTUxODVfbDFxa293cDcxOTMzdDd2MS83MTk2MjgvVmVyeS1CaWctQ2xpdC5yYXJ8NzE5NjI4fDI1ZjI3Mjc3NTVhMDRkOHxWZXJ5X0JpZ19DbGl0LnJhcnxsZXRpdGJpdC5uZXR8NA==" />
   <div class="dlBlock">
   <div class="title">
   <div class="top"></div>
   <!--<h4></h4>-->
   <span style="font-size:16px">Download file&nbsp;
With the <b>expectation</b> minute and <b> viewing </b> Site  <b style="color:#FFFFFF;"></b></span>

   </div>
   <div class="cont c2" align="center">
   <br /><br />
   <img src='http://letitbit.net/cap.php?jpg=2b446e355185.jpg' border='0'>
   <input type='text' maxlength='6' size='10' name='cap' class='name-login' style='width:80px; font-size:18px;background: url(http://images.letitbit.net/image/inpText_h25_bg.gif) top repeat-x; border: #838383 1px solid;'>
   <input name="frameset" type="submit" class="newb" onMouseOver="this.className='newb2'" onMouseOut="this.className='newb'" value='Download file' />
   <input type="hidden" name="uid2" value="2b446e355185" />
    <br>
        Enter the symbols you see in the  images        </div>

   <center><br><a href="http://bonusfile.com/comments.php?oid=Very-Big-Clit.rar"></a></center>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="uid5" value="2245376a60aebc53938549a0c4716a9d" />
   <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="2b446e355185" />
   <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Very-Big-Clit.rar" />
   <input type="hidden" name="pin" value="719628" />
   <input type="hidden" name="realuid" value="25f2727755a04d8" />
   <input type="hidden" name="realname" value="Very_Big_Clit.rar" />
   <input type="hidden" name="host" value="letitbit.net" />

   <input type="hidden" name="ssserver" value="r54" />
   <input type="hidden" name="sssize" value="5526201" />
   <input type="hidden" name="optiondir" value="4" />
</form>
```

Also, this may be because the request is from Russia (so things in the code may differ), but I only have this for cookies:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curlm.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.letitbit.net   TRUE    /   FALSE   1253169348  country RU
.letitbit.net   TRUE    /   FALSE   1221546947  access  deleted
letitbit.net    FALSE   /   FALSE   1221546947  ref_full    deleted
letitbit.net    FALSE   /   FALSE   1221546947  ref_site    deleted
.letitbit.net   TRUE    /   FALSE   1253946948  reserv  19b668119b69af967c1e919c0b684e48
```

That is exactly what is stored with the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE option.